# How to model virus spread over distinct days?

Tags: python, simulation, scipy, discrete-distributions

Say I want to model a simple virus spreading over 45 people with a transmission probability of 5%. If I choose my population to be exclusively hospital workers, assuming they work every day, I could model the first day as:

```
n=45
p=0.05
print(n*p) #2.25
virus_pmf = [binom.pmf(r, n, p) for r in range(45)]
plt.scatter(range(15),virus_pmf[0:15])
```

[image: 2.25 expected value of infections]
my question is, how would I model the 2nd day? If 2.25 people are infected, would I round this down to 2 infections because I cant have a partial infection? then the 2nd day would be similar, except I would model 45-2=43 non-infected people that are being infected by (1+2)=3 contagious people, so I would increase my rate to 0.05*3=0.15?

Comment: You might find it helpful to clarify your sense of "model."  Here, the model estimates *rates* but your question seems to focus on *predictions:* those are different things!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a variety of answers to this question depending on how and why you are doing the model.

This is really a question about *dynamical* modeling rather than statistical modeling (statistical modeling to estimate the parameters of the kind of model you propose is a much bigger can of worms ...), but since it deals with probabilistic outcomes maybe it isn't off-topic here ...

The classic answer would be to create a [Reed-Frost model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Frost_model), a stochastic discrete-time, discrete-state model. This simplest case assumes that the time step of the stochastic model and the *generation time* of the disease are the same, so that no-one stays infectious for more than (in your case) one day. (This is unrealistic for most directly transmitted diseases, but would be reasonable if for example workers realized that they were infected after one day and self-isolated.) In this case your model would be (with $i(t)$ = incidence (new cases) during time step $t$, $S(t)$ = number remaining susceptible at the *end* of time step $t$):

$$
\begin{split}
i(t) & \sim \textrm{Binomial}(p = 1-(1-\phi)^{i(t-1)},N= S(t-1)) \\
S(t) & = S(t-1) - i(t) \\
\end{split}
$$

here $\phi$ is the probability of a single infected person infecting a particular susceptible person: $(1-\phi)$ is the probability that they *don't* infect, $(1-\phi)^{i(t-1)}$ is the probability that *none* of the infected people infect the focal susceptible, and $1-(1-\phi)^{i(t-1)}$ is the probability that *at least one* of the infected people successfully infects ...

There is R code for simulating individual Reed-Frost epidemics, and ensembles of epidemics, [here](https://bbolker.github.io/math4mb/notes/epi1.pdf) (if you look around a bit you can find the source file on GitHub); there is a discrete-time stochastic SIR model in Python [here](http://epirecip.es/epicookbook/chapters/sir-stochastic-discretestate-discretetime/python), corresponding to the more general "let people stay infectious for more than one time period" case discussed below ...

Note that this differs from your model specification, which says (as far as it goes) that the *per capita* probability of infection is a constant 5%; this is more like a *Greenwood model* in the epidemiological literature (which says that the *per capita* probability of infection is a constant as long as at least one person is infected). In this case we would have $i(t) \sim \textrm{Binomial}(p = \phi,N= S(t-1))$ (where $\phi$ now has a slightly different meaning).

In either of these cases you would use `binom.rvs(n, p)` in Python to select the number of infections in the next time step.

Some things to think about:

- you might want to let people stay infectious for more than one time period. In the simplest case, if their recovery probability per time period is $\gamma$, then you would add a variable $I(t)$ (because you have to keep track of *prevalence* independently of *incidence*, replace $i(t-1)$ with $I(t-1)$ in the calculation of the incidence, and make the recovery $r(t)$ equal to a binomial draw with $n=I(t-1), p = \gamma$; then $I(t) = I(t-1) - r(t) + i(t)$ (if $\gamma=1$ we get back to the previous model).
- you might not like the fact that you're getting a single stochastic realization from your model. You could:

  - revert to a deterministic model (e.g. with your [Greenwood-style] model set the incidence equal to the *expected* number of cases $i(t) = \phi S(t-1)$, which does give you fractional individuals (!)
  - run the simulation many times and compute whatever summaries you want (e.g. mean number infected at each time, 95% quantiles ...)
  - if you're feeling very thorough, you could keep track of the full probability distribution: the probability of $\{I(t) = n\}$ is $\sum_j \textrm{Prob}(I(t-1) = n-j) \cdot \textrm{Prob}((\Delta I)(t) = j)$ (where $(\Delta I)(t)$ is the same as $i(t)$ above if the infectious period is only one time step — otherwise you have to consider both the binomial variation from infection and the  binomial variation from recovery, which starts to explain why most people do this by simulating ensembles of stochastic realizations ...)

Answer (score 1):

> Say I want to model a simple virus spreading over 45 people with a transmission probability of 5%.
>
> If 2.25 people are infected, would I round this down to 2 infections because I cant have a partial infection?

You could model the average evolution of the virus spread, and this might give results like *"2.25 people are infected"*. Such cases of non-integer infections are not realistic, but they might be reasonable as a model.

As an alternative you could model the distribution of the potential paths of the spread. In that case you don't have to deal with non-integer numbers and instead you will have something like "in 25% of the cases there will be 2 people infected, and in 75% of the cases there will be 3 people infected".

In the case of a model that works with discrete time steps you could use a Markov chain to model the evolution of the spread from day to day. Alternatively, for non-discrete evolution you could model this as a phase type distribution. Or, you don't bother with this and run a bunch of simulations or approximate the discrete distribution with a continuous distribution.

---

Example:

Your exact problem is not very clear, but here is one way to handle it

(assuming a simple dynamics with a constant 5% daily probability of getting the virus, and no effects of recovery, influence of number of people already sick, etc.)

If you have 45 people, and everyday the probability that a person acquires the virus is 0.05, then after $k$ days the probability to have acquired the virus is $1-(1-0.05)^k$ and the distribution is binomial:

[image: example of modelling the distribution versus modelling the expected value]

The left image shows the modelling of the distribution. You have discrete values for the number of infected people (on the x-axis). Each curve shows the distribution for a different day. So on day one you do not have 2.25 infected people, but *on average* 2.25 infected people. This average, or expected value is shown in the right image, which shows the modelling of that average number of infected people.

R-code for image:

```
layout( matrix(c(1:4),2, byrow = 1))

k = c(0:45) 

plot(k,dbinom(k,45,0.05), xlab = "number infections", ylab = "probability", type = "l", ylim = c(0,0.30), main = "model of probability distribution of \n number of cumulative infections")


for (i in c(1:5)) {
   days = c(1,5,10,20,40)[i]
   col = i
   lines(k, dbinom(k,45,1-(1-0.05)^days), col = col)
   points(k, dbinom(k,45,1-(1-0.05)^days), pch = 20, col = col)
   m = 45*(1-(1-0.05)^days)
   text(m, dbinom(floor(m),45,1-(1-0.05)^days), paste0(days, " days"), col = col, pos = 3)
}

d = 1:40
plot(d,45*(1-(1-0.05)^d), xlab = "days", ylab = "expectation value", main = "model of distribution of \n number of cumulative infections", ylim = c(0,45), type = "l")
points(d,45*(1-(1-0.05)^d), pch= 20)
```

Comment: This is fair, and stays out of the weeds whereas my answer dives into them, but note that the OP asks how to model the *second* day of the epidemic ...

Comment: @BenBolker it is difficult to go into the exact way of modeling the second day as not much details have been given (is this every day simply 5% infections or is there some more complex dynamics?). I focussed on the issue about how one could deal with non-integer, $45 \times 0.05 = 2.25$, infections. One way is to model the probability distribution of the infections.

Comment: Fair enough. I think what they want is closer to the Reed-Frost model I described. I hesitated about providing code because I didn't want to remember how to do it in Python ...